# Disable firewall for all network profiles on Windows Server 2008 R2 through GPO

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-firewall

I've been trying to disable firewall on a number of Windows Server 2008 R2 machines for all network profiles using GPO, but it seems to be working only for domain profile so far.

In Group Policy Management mmc on W2k3 machine, when I try to edit GPO (**Windows Firewall Properties**, like on a screenshot below) - sub-tree `Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security - Local Group Policy Object` is missing, which is normal, since there were no Firewall with Advanced Security before W2k8.

Is this possible to add this functionality?

[image]

All DCs are Windows Server 2003 machines.

- *Forest functional level*: **2000**
- *Domain functional level*: **2003**

How can one configure various network profiles on W2k8 R2 machines with all DCs running on W2k3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to launch the group policy management console from a Windows 7 or 2008 R2 machine to manage these new policies. They won't be available in the GPMC on a 2003 server.